# CSS: height / overflow-y:hidden not having effect on div size

Tags: html, css

I have the following div with these two identifiers:

```
.locations_wrapper
```

and

```
#tenn_location_wrapper
```

the `height` of the latter is set to `600px` and the height of the former is set to `500px`. I have set `overflow-y:hidden` to each `div` identifier and yet, when the div is rendered in Chrome, the height is `2215px`. Is there any way to keep it from expanding to this height and adhere to the asigned `height` values?

Here is a fiddle with the HTML and CSS:

https://jsfiddle.net/ft74v68f/2/

N.B. the fiddle does not totally illustrate the problem as the Bg image, which is of a size 2048px * 1365px, is not rendering.

my `<body>` tag ends in the middle of its child, `locations_wrapper`. However when I increase the `height` of the body element such that it doesn't overflow, the heights of its children are still not enforced.

Comment: Can you show us the css? In a fiddle maybe?

Comment: And the actual HTML please. Show us the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with your

```
#tenn_location_wrapper {
    display:table !important
}

.locations_wrapper {
    display:table !important
}
```

You replace this by `display:block`, and you'll see it's fixed. Only use tables for using tabular data, as using them to style your page leads to a lot of issues.

Comment: oder Schwester. It was literally the one thing I did not understand in my css which I was suspicious of but alas I did not RTFM.